# refstepcounter in tcolorbox option

Tags: counters, tcolorbox, key-value

I want to increment a counter and update the current label in the `phantom` key of the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) environment, but it is not working, as can be seen in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=6cm,margin=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentlabel{\@currentlabel}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{tcolorbox}[phantom=\refstepcounter{mycounter}]
  counter value: \themycounter\ \currentlabel.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[phantom=\refstepcounter{mycounter}]
  counter value: \themycounter\ \currentlabel.
\end{tcolorbox}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  counter value: \themycounter\ \currentlabel.
\end{tcolorbox}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  counter value: \themycounter\ \currentlabel.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The output follows

[image: output of mwe].

Observe that `\@currentlabel` is not updated when the counter is incremented using the `phantom` key.

Is this a bug or I am missing something here?

Comment: The manual of `tcolorbox` clearly states, that the code of the `phantom` key hook is executed in a LaTeX group, so only global operations can survive.

Comment: `\@currentlabel` is *only* `\protected@edef` defined, so it is not global.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't dived into the internals but it looks like `tcolorbox` is preserving the value of `\@currentlabel` so that it has the same value that it had before the start of the `tcolorbox`. On the other hand, it is incrementing your counter and it does allow you to assign a label to it using the `label` argument. If instead you use:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[step=mycounter,label=one]
  Counter value: \themycounter, \currentlabel.
  This is \ref{one}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Then the output is:

[image]

That is, using `label=` correctly sets the reference to your counter. Behind the scenes `tcolorbox` is probably writing the label directly to the auxfile. (Note that `step=...` is a shortcut to `phantom=\refstepcounter...`). So the referencing is working correctly, but to access it you need to use `label=...`

Answer (score 3):

Andrew has provided already a solution, I just want to show, that the `\@currentlabel` change does not survive outside of `phantom` code.

The doubled `\refstepcounter` command for the third box is done on purpose!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=6cm,margin=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentlabel{\@currentlabel}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  counter value: \themycounter\ \currentlabel.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[phantom={\global\refstepcounter{mycounter}}]
  counter value: \themycounter\ \ref{Box::two}% Should not work
\end{tcolorbox} 


\refstepcounter{mycounter}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}
  counter value: \themycounter\ \ref{Box::three}%
\end{tcolorbox} \label{Box::three}%

\refstepcounter{mycounter}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  counter value: \themycounter\ \currentlabel.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]